# JPA Postgres float mapping/ordering

Tags: postgresql, sorting, jpa, natural-sort

We develop a Java EE application that uses a Postgres database as persistence medium. Some of our entity attributes are mapped as float. Sorting this columns leads to the following result:

```
  SCORE
  1.0
  100.2
  2.0
  20.0
  3.0
```

The result I've expected is:

```
  SCORE
  1.0
  2.0
  3.0
  20.0
  100.2
```

The float attrributes are mapped with datatype float(8) in postgres database. With the following plain sql query sorting works as expected:

```
SELECT score FROM Evaluation ORDER BY score::float
```

Also changing the column type to "real" works. Is there any way (except using column definition) to get this work with jpa?

Comment: Very strange, given that the documentation says: *PostgreSQL accepts float(1) to float(24) as selecting the real type*, so float(8) and real are in fact the same type. (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)

Comment: That sure sounds like your column is defined as `text` (or `varchar`) please show us the CREATE TABLE statement (or the output of the `\dt` command in psql). Sorting a real flot column **does** work correctly. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d95f2/1

Comment: Please show your JPA @Entity mapping, your table definition, and how you're requesting that the data be sorted.

Comment: Do you have a custom domain type lurking around? Please show the output of the `\dT float` command when run in psql connected to the same database this test was run in. Note the capital `t'.

Comment: That´s strange. I´ve created an float column at home on my private machine and sorting works as expected. I will have an look on the create table statement tomorrow @work. The column(s) at work are mapped as float ;). I don´t think that the problem belongs to JPA, because my sql query tool also shows me the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for your effort :(. I had have a look again on the domain model. They saved the score within two columns. One column is float, the other is an varchar. Sorting action sorts the varchar column, so alphanumeric sorting is ok.